# How to Import https://github.com/go-test/deep into Your Golang Test

Tags: go, go-testing

I'm new to Golang.

My go version: 1.17.8

Trying write tests to compare strcuts.
Found [this](https://github.com/go-test/deep) lib can show you which fields exactly equivalent.
So thought of using it over reflect.DeepEqual

Here's my test go file,

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"

    "github.com/go-test/deep"
)


func TestDeepEqual(t *testing.T) {
    os.Remove("_decktesting.txt")

    d := newDeck()
    d.saveToFile("_decktesting.txt")
    l := newDeckFromFile("_decktesting.txt")

    if diff := deep.Equal(d, l); diff != nil {
        t.Error(diff)
    }
}
```

Here's what it says when try to test,

```
➜ go get

go-training/cards on  develop [!] via  v1.17.8 
➜ go test
# go-training/cards
deck_test.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/go-test/deep" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/github.com/go-test/deep (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/ssamarasin/go/src/github.com/go-test/deep (from $GOPATH)
FAIL    go-training/cards [setup failed]

go-training/cards on  develop [!] via  v1.17.8 
➜ go install github.com/go-test/deep@latest
package github.com/go-test/deep is not a main package
```

Can someone please explain how I can use this lib to compare my structs?

Thank you

Comment: Use `go get` instead of the `go install` command.

Comment: Step 1: Read what go help install explains what go install does instead of guessing. Step 2: Use go get.

Answer (score 1):

```
GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/go-test/deep
```

Comment: Thanks mate,
It worked

Did that plus,